# Копирование сайтa Drupal и перенос на другой хостинг и домен

Tags: mysql, cms, drupal

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно скопировать сайт на CMS Drupal? На данный момент выполнил просто экспорт базы данных, после сделал копию сайта с хостинга. И залил на новый хостинг, в директорию домена, скопированный сайт, и через phpmyadmin импортировал БД. Вылезла вот такая ошибка...

Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rvsrru_c1035'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/aufhcrw3/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы правильно перенести сайт на CMS друпал, читайте информацию тут - https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/backing-up-and-migrating-a-site/migrating-a-site

А так вкратце - удаляете кэш, копируете БД, копируйте сайт, заливаете бд, меняете пути в htcaccess, меняете информацию в setings.php. Далее настаиваете модули, меняете пути к фото. И меняете дискрипшены, если копия сайта загружена в интернете, дабы избежать проблем с индексацией.

Если кто-то что-то добавит или меня поправит. Я думаю всем остальным будет полезно.